# Merge two zoo objects with data summed up for column with same names

Tags: r, zoo

I would like to merge two zoo objects, with data summed up if the column names are the same.For example,

```
ZooObject1
Date A B C
1/1/2012 2 4 8
1/2/2012 1 3 9
1/3/2012 3 6 4

ZooObject2
Date D B E
1/1/2012 3 4 9
1/2/2012 2 7 2
1/3/2012 1 8 8

MergedObject
Date A B C D E
1/1/2012 2 8 8 3 9
1/2/2012 1 10 9 2 2
1/3/2012 3 14 4 1 8
```

In this case, since both `ZooObject1` and `ZooObject2` has column named "B", the figures of column B in the merged zoo object will be sum of figures of "B" in `ZooObject1` and that of "B" in `ZooObject2`

Any simple code can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate the common names and the names unique to each input and then put it all together fixing up any mangled names:

```
both <- intersect(names(z1), names(z2))
only1 <- setdiff(names(z1), both)
only2 <- setdiff(names(z2), both)

setNames(cbind(z1[, only1], z2[, only2], z1[, both] + z2[, both]),
    c(only1, only2, both))
```

This works at least on the sample input.  There may or may not need to be some changes if your actual problem varies from it in some important way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not beautiful, but this will do the job:

```
library(reshape2)
z <- merge(ZooObject1, ZooObject2)
z <- melt(cbind(data.frame(t=time(z)), as.data.frame(z)), id.vars="t")
z$variable <- gsub("\\..*$", "", z$variable)
z <- dcast(z, t ~ variable, fun.aggregate=sum)
z <- zoo(z[,-1], z[,1])
```

For `zoo` objects, the time index must be unique, so this approach converts the zoo objects back to data frames, with the time index as a column, aggregates and then converts the results back to a `zoo` object. It's not bullet proof: if the field names in your `zoo` objects have `.` in their names, it will break!